# Why do I get NativeGestures in Qt rather than just Gestures

Tags: qt, touch, gesture

I thought I should take a look at Gesture and touch events with my Qt application following the documentation:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/gestures-overview.html

However the event I am getting is a QEvent::NativeGesture not the QEvent::Gesture the documentation talks about.  The Qt labs blog post I found says NativeGestures should be converted to Qt Gestures:

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/04/23/gestures-in-short/

Do I have to recompile Qt now that I have a touch screen?

(I have Windows 7 with a Dell touch screen monitor so I have the equipment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I think I need to accept the touch events at the same time as grabbing the Gesture.  Where as initially I was just grabbing the gesture.

```
    viewport()->grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
    viewport()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
```